# Shortcut for changing font size

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, settings, font-size

Does anybody know if there is a shortcut or something similar for changing the font size in the text editor in Visual Studio 2008?

What I mean is something like Ctrl + mouse wheel like in Firefox.

Accessing the Options window and then selecting Environment > Fonts and Colors is fine if you don't have to change the font size all the time, but in my case, I would like to be able to change it depending on what I am doing (writing and reading code or just reading it).

I guess I could create two almost identical settings files and import them whenever I want, but that is even slower.

Comment: Control + scrolling mouse can change font size in vs 2019 on windows

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the Macros explorer under samples/accessibility there is an IncreaseTextEditorFontSize and a DecreaseTextEditorFontSize. Bind those to some keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @Dolphin In VS2010 under Options-Environment-Keyboard you can bind the commands View.ZoomIn and View.ZoomOut. These are the equivalent of the mouse wheel zooming.

Answer (score 213):

You'll probably find these shortcuts useful:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to zoom in.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to zoom out.

Those characters are period and comma, respectively.

Comment: They don't work in VS2019.

Comment: @Fizz - I just verified and it works on VS2019 for me. Unless you changed the default I assume it should work for you as well.

Comment: @BornToCode: no I haven't changed any defaults. Using 16.11.9 barely installed on a machine that didn't have any VS installed before.

Comment: Is there a way to increase *all* font sizes? I know can go to `Tools in Menu -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors`, but then I have to change the settings for *each* window/component. I wouldn't mind, but I often log in remotely to the same machine using screens of wildly differing sizes.

Comment: @user2023370 - There's a Windows setting to increase text by 125% etc. you can also export and import VS settings with the font sizes you defined.

Answer (score 128):

Ctrl + MouseWheel on active editor.

Comment: This suddenly quit working for me.  Is this defined somewhere?

Answer (score 17):

I am using Visual Studio 2017 , I found below can change font size

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Ctrl + MouseWheel works on almost anything...not just visual studio

Answer (score 10):

In visual studio 2019 you can use,

Either:

**Ctrl + Shift + .**  To increase

**Ctrl + Shift + ,** To decrease

Or

Go to
**Tools > Options... > Environment > Fonts and Colors**

Answer (score 8):

Use : 
Tools in Menu -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check out the [VS 2010 Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx) that was just released. The new editor should have this.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + **Alt** + MouseWheel will work in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: You don't need the `Alt`. It's `Ctrl + MouseWheel` as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can chnage font size by ctrl + mousewheel.

OR

tools --> options --> environment --> font and color.

Detail with screenshot is mentonied [here](https://blossomprogramming.blogspot.in/2017/08/change-font-and-size-in-visual-studio.html)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**Ctrl** + **-**     to minimize

**Ctrl** + **+**     to maximize

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio code if your front is too small or too big, then you just need to zoom out or zoom in. To do that you just have to do:

- For zoom in : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> (ctrl and equal both)
- For zoom out: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (ctrl and - both)

Answer (score 0):

For currently latest version of VScode (version 1.76.2),

simply add- `"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true` in setting.json file

and now you can simply press ctrl + mousewheel scroll to zoom in and out.