# Can I quickly dial up font sizes for the VS IDE without a mouse?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, editor, mousewheel, font-size

Maybe this isn't a "programming question" per se, but it relates to the coding process:

One of the really neat features I like about the WPF-ized VS IDE is being able to hit Ctrl (I think it is) and thumb the mouse wheel to quickly change font size in the code editor.

For work (desktop PC) that works great, but at home, on my laptop, I can't figure out how to accomplish it (other than going into Properties or whatever and changing font size there, which is obviously way less "handy" (no pun intended)).

Is there a quick way to change edit font size without resorting to the dialog accessed via the menu?

Comment: Do try using google more.  Type "vs2010 increase font size" and take the 2nd hit.

Comment: @Hans: What have you got against Bing? <g,d&r>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the shortcut in the Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard shortcuts for View.ZoomIn and View.ZoomOut. I think they are by default: CTRL + Shift + Comma for zoom out and CTRL + Shift + Period for zoom in .

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/04/15/visual-studio-2010-zooming-keyboard-commands-global-zoom.aspx

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Format` is the place where you can change as per your need

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a scroll wheel, you'll have to create your own macro to do this. Check out the first answer in this post:
[Shortcut for changing font size in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898964/shortcut-for-changing-font-size-in-visual-studio)